# Identifying a coaxial/RF connector

Tags: rf, connector, identification

I'm trying to identify the following miniature female RF coaxial connector found on an antenna input of a cheap DVB-T receiver (Sencor brand). I would like to identify the type so that I can get a matching male connector. The inner diameter of the receptacle measures 3.3 mm and the depth is approximately 4 mm. The inner surface is smooth. There are no threads or indents visible. Since it is on a DVB-T receiver, I'm guessing the connector probably has 75 ohm impedance.

[image]

Other dimensions I could measure with calipers (approx. where I can only do an estimate):

[image]

The closest match I could find is the front end of a SMC plug (without the threads), however the barrel is just slightly too large to fit (3.7 mm diameter). MCX also appears too large (3.8 mm).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have the mating cable? Can you include a picture of the male connector?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have the matching cable.

Comment: upvote for the quality of presentation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me like an MCX connector. For example, this one from [Amphenol](https://www.amphenolrf.com/252151-75.html):

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm not sure why this one doesn't seem to have the dielectric protruding around the center contact like yours, when it is shown in the general diagram below.

The 3.5 mm inner diameter you measured is pretty close to correct:

[image]

(Image source: [Amphenol](https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/mcx-connectors.html))

Comment: Thanks. That Amphenol part is indeed very close to what is mounted on my device. It seems likely to me now that this is MCX. I don't have a male connector at hand, but I'll get one and try it out. I was looking at the outer diameter of the MCX plug dimensions and I missed that the plug has a spring design and can fit into narrower receptacles.

Comment: The protruding dielectric might be the difference between 75 ohm and 50 ohm. Based on some searching it appears that 50 ohm MCX connectors have visible dielectric while 75 ohm connectors do not, but I didn't find a conclusive source for that.

Comment: Wikipedia has a picture including the dielectric here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCX_connector

Comment: Thanks again. I just verified that a male MCX connector indeed fits my device.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like an MCX. The inner diameter of the receptacle is spec'd at 3.45 +/- 0.03 mm, which is pretty close to your drawn width of 3.3 mm, and has some measurement error.  The receptacle depth is spec'd at 4.0 mm, which matches your drawing. See dimensions labeled B and G in this MCX spec sheet:

http://www.xmultiple.com/Suggested-MCX-5.htm